# ListBoxItem does not stretch in ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am creating an application for Windows Phone 8(silverlight). I want to display data in two columns in the ListBox. I use [this method](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/03/31/wrappanel-is-great-so-please-stop-using-it/).In this article is a demonstration project with the code. Here is the basic code for output:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

It works, but the data do not stretch, to the right is the free space. 
[image]

I have tried many options

```
<ListBox...>
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

....

inserted HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch"

but they do not work. Tell me how I stretch data width? I need to have each column occupied half of the total width.

This is code my DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate" >


        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>




            <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AddInfo}"  />
                </Grid>
            </Button>

        </Grid>


</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I try to 
<toolkit:WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
but this not work - to the right is the free space

Comment: @EugenePodskal `UniformGrid` does not exist in Silverlight/WP

Comment: Can you also post the markup for your "ItemDataTemplate"?  We need to see how you are setting it up.

Comment: I added the code ItemDataTemplate in question

Answer (score 0):

In Your data template your should add Height="100%" for vertical Stretch or weidth="100%" for horizontal Stretch 
that is inside textblock

```
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Height="//some vale in decimal" Widht="//some vale in decimal" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AddInfo}" Height="//some vale in decimal" Widht="//some vale in decimal" />
            </Grid>
```

Comment: I do need a not  fixed width